# Elements no longer inherit data-theme from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, data-theme

According to the [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-themes.html) any form element inside a container will adopt the `data-theme` of that container

> Query Mobile has a rich theming system that gives you full control of
>   how pages and forms are styled. By default all form elements inside a
>   container will automatically adopt the same theme color swatch as
>   their parent. This allows form elements to blend into their layouts
>   with minimal work. The data-theme attribute can be applied to any
>   individual form element to apply any of the lettered theme color
>   swatches to create contrast and emphasis in your designs.

However it seems that with the most recent release of jQuery Mobile (1.2) this is no longer true, I've noticed that form elements now inherit from the `data-theme` of the `page` instead of their more immediate parent.

For example given the following markup

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header"><h3>Header</h3></div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
        <li>
            <input type="button" value="test" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <select >
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </li>
         <li>
           <div data-role="fieldcontain"  data-theme="c" >
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"  data-theme="c"  data-type="horizontal" >
            <legend>Group Size</legend>

            <input type="radio" name="testRdoGrp" id="testRdoGrp1" checked="checked" value="1" />
            <label for="testRdoGrp1">1</label>       
            <input type="radio" name="testRdoGrp" id="testRdoGrp2" value="2" />
            <label for="testRdoGrp2">2</label>

         </fieldset>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer"><h3>Footer</h3></div>
</div>
```

Jsbins:

[With JQM 1.1](http://jsbin.com/ilinup/4/edit)

[With JQM 1.2](http://jsbin.com/ilinup/5/edit)

Using JQM 1.1 the input, select and radio group will use the *c theme* swatch (inherited from the `listview`), but when using JQM 1.2 the input, select and radio group will instead use the *a* swatch.

This seems to be the case even with container's that have the `data-role="fieldcontain" (such as the radio group in the example I provided).

Setting the `data-theme` directly on the element still works but besides that I think the previous behavior makes for cleaner markup in my case I have quite a bit of markup and I would rather not have to go through each element and individually add the `data-theme`.

Does any one know of some way to revert to the 1.1 behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found this change in behavior documented anywhere, but I've found a partial workaround for this issue. Adding the swatch using the `ui-body-` (plus the letter for the `swatch`) class causes the elements to inherit the data-theme from the parent.

For example

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-body-c" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
    <li>
        <input type="button" value="test" />
    </li>
</ul>
```